# How do i encapsulate an ajax request using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, encapsulation

i am implementing a PHP application, i am using AJAX heavily in forms to send and retrieve values. the typical jQuery function i am implementing is

```
(function($){
$.fn.saveCountry = function(destinationUrl) {
    this.click(function(){
        var formData = $('form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:  'path/to/files/models/directory/process.php',
            data: 'option=savecountry&'+formData,
            success: function(msg){
                if(msg === 'empty') {
                    alert('Required Values Missing');
                } else if(msg == 'DR'){
                    alert('Duplicate Entry Found');
                } else {
                    destinationUrl(msg);
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
}($));
```

the problem with the above function is it exposes the application structure of my application for example. the object `url:  'path/to/files/models/directory/process.php',` reveals the information about the directory structure i am using. this is a kind of threat as anyone with the access to  console will be able to monitor what is happening with the request and could misuse it. is there anyway i could hide this data from the outside world?

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately no.

The user will always be able to find out the URL of the ajax request if they wish to.

It can be as simple as opening up firebug and watching the requests that are made.

What I'd sugest is some kind of URL abstration such as URL Rewriting in order to hide the physical structure of your file system. This way you'll not have that specific concern about people seeing your URLs.

Comment: yes, one solution of what i thought about is making use of `mod_rewrite`. i am a novice to javascript and jquery, earlier i had heard about javascript MVC, or object oriented Javascript, so i thought may be JS may have some kind of solution for this. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a PHP programmer (touched it many years ago), so I'll give you a general answer.

Simply create a proxy page, which hides the internal workings of your application. The proxy page is just a go in between the browser and the application itself. What it does is translating an ID that you pass along with the AJAX call to a function in the application (it could do more than that, but I try to keep this simple). It passes along the data you submitted in your AJax call. The proxy would send back any data passed back from the function to the browser.

The JavaScript code would look pretty much the same as the code you already have. The only changes would be that the `url` would be the URL of your proxy page and the `data` would also contain an ID with the value that corresponds to the value of the function that you wish to execute in the proxy.

All your AJAX calls can be routed through this proxy page, since each function would have an unique ID.

It's a bit programming upfront, but when you've done this once, you can reuse parts of the code in future projects.

Comment: sounds useful, something is clicking on my side after reading your answer. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

No. You need to write your server-side code in a way that arbitrary requests won't cause any problems.

Comment: that is to be done. but just as a precautionary measure i was thinking if there was any workaround for this. i am using OOP in my PHP application. the basic idea of mine was to hide the structure and route all the PHP request from index.php, now this AJAX calls kills all the purpose :)

Comment: Security by oscurity is bad. And why not just route the AJAX calls through your index.php, too?